# cython return statement gives a built-in method instead of integer

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am working with cython on wrapping a library of mine. I'm a rookie programmer so this is giving me some growing pains. I'm going through examples right now and I've compiled a wrapping library for a Rectangle.cpp class with Rectangle.h and a rect.pyx and setup.py. Now I am running it with test.py

I have a **rect.pyx** file:

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getLength()
        int getHeight()
        int getArea()
        void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def getLength(self):
        return self.thisptr.getLength()
   def getHeight(self):
        return self.thisptr.getHeight()
    def getArea(self):
        return self.thisptr.getArea()
   def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
```

I have built it into a library and I call it with this file **test.py**

```
from rect import PyRectangle

rec = PyRectangle(0,0,4,4)

length = rec.getLength
print(length)
```

But when I run this what I get back is `<built-in method getLength of rect.PyRectangle object at 0x7fb174f19240>`

Why do I not get an int returned? How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Call your method:

Change this:

```
rec.getLength
```

to this:

```
rec.getLength()
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to take a break.